# how to format inputs on python 3.2

Tags: python, input, split

```
while True: 

    letter,Text,numRails= input("").split('\"')
    if numRails ==(""):
        numRails=(2)
        plainText= Text.strip()
    numRails=int(numRails)


    if letter.strip() == "E" or "e":
        x =Encrypt(numRails,Text)

    elif letter.strip()=="D" or "d":
        x =scramble2Decrypt(numRails,Text)

    else: print("invalid encryption command")
```

E "WEAREDISCOVEREDGO" 2
I need to be able to input all 3 variables on the same line. however I want to have some conditional statements. but I don't know how to do that. like do I just do it as you would normally do if it was just one variable or there's a specific way you have to do this ?

Comment: I forgot to mention the quotations are necessary for the input but shouldn't affect my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note if conditions are wrong! it always evaluates to True:

```
 letter.strip() == "E" or "e":
 #                      ^^^^ always True
```

should be:

```
 letter.strip() in ["E", "e"]:
```

Similar mistake is present in second if code.

Note: a Boolean equivalent of a non-empty string is always True e.g.

```
>>> bool("") # bool of empty string 
False
>>> bool(" ") # bool of non-empty string 
True
>>> bool("e")
True
```

So for this reason your if condition e.g. `letter.strip() == "E" or "e":` == `letter.strip() == "E" or True:` == `Ture`

As @[roippi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2581969/roippi) is suggesting in comment, you can further simplify if conditional expressions just as follows:

```
letter.strip().lower() == 'e':
```

Comment: Optionally letter.strip().lower() == 'e'

Comment: @roippi Yes I would like to add in my answer Thanks!